# How to send an email to customers who is having an item in their wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, email-reminders

Is there a way to send a reminder email to customers who has added items to their wishlist and forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to make a stand alone script to set in cron.

In that script you can get the wish-list collection and customer data and add your filter condition to filter data and send email according to final data.

Comment: Can you give me an example working code?